# Rendering images through TreelistEx

Tags: media-library, glass-mapper

Environment: **Sitecore 9.0.2 + Glassmapper**

I am trying to create a component like this.
[image]

So in the template, for the images (stored in Sitecore Media Library), I have taken a field of type TreeListEx.

From a TreeListEx type field, Sitecore returns the item-ids of the selected item.

So, when I use the syntax `@Html.Glass().RenderImage(item, x => x, null, true)`, the parameter `item` is the Sitecore Id of the image item and the output of the above syntax is an empty string.

1. Am I missing something?
2. Should I make a call to Sitecore for each media item Id to get the item and pass it to the Glass Mapper?

I did saw the link https://horizontalintegration.blog/2018/02/07/sitecore-glass-mapper-gettargetobjectoflamba-exception/ and believe Ram is also passing the Id.

Comment: Try solution in this article http://suhasshiv.com/2017/02/18/TDS-Glassmapper-CustomTypes/, you can  configure glass mapper to use a type instead of guids for list fields. use Glass.Mapper.Sc.Fields.Image as your item type.

Comment: @VipinBanka: Thanks for the link. I went through the first approach and it worked.

Comment: @VipinBanka: Please provide it in as answer, so I can mark the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your model to have the type of your `TreelistEx` field be an `IEnumerable<Glass.Mapper.Sc.Fields.Image>` instead of using `ID`s. Something like:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Glass.Mapper.Sc.Fields;

[SitecoreType(TemplateId = "{TEMPLATEID}")]
public class ImageGroup
{
    [SitecoreField(FieldId = "{FIELDID}")]
    public virtual IEnumerable<Image> SelectedImages { get; set; }
}
```

> ### Note
>
> If you're doing this with code generation with TDS and Glass Mapper, you can use the `CustomData` property of your field item in TDS to have code generation set the model property type automatically.
>
> [image: Code generation properties in TDS]

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new child item template lets say `ChildImage` template which will contain the `Image` field. Parent template will have `TreeListEx` field which will allow to select child items (`ChildImage`).

***Parent Datasource***

[image]
***ChildImage***

[image]

***Class***

```
[SitecoreType(TemplateId=I_ImageListConstants.TemplateIdString )] 
public partial interface I_ImageList : IGlassBase 
{
    [SitecoreField(I_ImageListConstants.SlidesFieldName)]
    IEnumerable<_ChildImage> Images  {get; set;}    
}
```

***View***

```
foreach (var i in Images)
{               
    @RenderImage(i, x => x.Image,  isEditable: true)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pitching in. Due to certain restrictions, I cannot go for the datasource approach. So, I am going with PageContext. Hence stuck with the Ids of the images.